# How to quit the Story Mode?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I just bought a PS3 Slim and GTA V. When I open GTA V, it automatically opens up in Story Mode. I don't want to play the role playing aspect of it, I just wanna play the regular version, like, the one where you steal cars, shoot guns, but not the story mode. Can someone help me quit the story mode please?

Answer (score 10):

There is no "regular mode", the game only has story mode and GTA Online. You first need to play until the end of the prologue and the first mission. After that, you can go around the city freely and cause all the damage you want, but well, most YouTubers and Twitch streamers play on GTA Online, so that's probably what you're thinking. You can switch to GTA Online through the pause menu, on the online tab (after completing the prologue), or by holding <kbd>Left-Alt</kbd> (keyboard) or down on the directional pad (controller), and navigating to the bottom of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

After completing the Prologue and first mission, with the cars, you can enter your phone, go to settings and then click on "Do Not Disturb". Turn that on. This prevents you from recieving phone calls that could possibly progress the storyline.

Apart from that, avoiding mission markers is the best you can do.

Answer (score -2):

Actually when you go into story mode, press menu and you’ll see a tab that says game tap game start a new game and you don’t have to do the missions. You can also get gta online and only do the beginning mission of gta v until the gta v logo shows up and you can play gta online

Comment: This answer is very wrong and badly spelt. First, clicking "New Game" resets your progress, why would you want that? Second, the question I think is asking for singleplayer without the story, not GTA Online.